# visual studio 12 html5/javascript app .exe

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have followed a tutorial on the internet on how to make a windows 8 app with html 5 / java script.
Now, when i click on debug, it will open the app, like it should.
But, how can i export this to .exe?
I have searched for it but the only thing people recommend me to do is look in a folder called:
`C:\Users\guus\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\myapp\myapp\bin\Debug`.
Since i cant see an .exe file in here after debugging i dont really know what i do wrong.
Also, i dont see an export button in the menu?
So, can anyone tell me how to export this to .exe?